# Should I ask questions about Maxima here at Math SE or at Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, stackexchange

I see that questions about Maxima (a computer algebra system) are asked both at the Math SE and at Stackoverflow. Where should I ask my question about Maxima? Does it depend on the type of question?

Comment: It does depend on the "type of question".  The basic dictum is that Questions about how to use software to accomplish a mathematical task are on topic here.  General support issues for Maxima or other software are off topic and should be directed to the mailing list or vendor specific resource.  StackOverflow is concerned with *programming* techniques, so it is conceivable a question could be on topic both places.

Comment: You can also have a look at questions tagged ([tag:maxima-software]) to see what kind of questions have been asked in the past.

Comment: It was only now that I learned that Macsyma is now Maxima.

Comment: ONLY ask the question here if it is about mathematics.  MOST Maxima/Macsyma questions are not about mathematics and should not be asked here.  Whether they should be asked in Stackoverflow, only they can determine, not us.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche They are not the same. Maxima is a fork from a very old (1982) version of Macsyma.